# Synonym for "by a single-click"

Tags: synonyms

I would like to describe that a software is very easy to use, especially for non-technical users.

So I guess I can say "By a single-click, the software can accomplish the task X".

Now, I would like more expressions like "by a single-click", could anyone suggest any?

Comment: A single click needs no hyphen as a noun phrase. A single-click adjective takes a hyphen to hold it together. Since we click all day and double-click occasionally, no need to specify single click, the default.

Comment: The software isn't accomplishing a task *by* or *with* a click, it is doing it *in response to* a click. It is the user who does the clicking.

Answer (score 1):

At a tap, the touch of a mouse, or a single swipe [i.e. of a touchscreen device] could be options.

These are variations on the long-established expression *at the touch of a button*

From [Macmillan Dictionary online](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/at-the-touch-of-a-button)

> At the touch of a button ​
>
> if a machine works at the touch of a  button, it works extremely quickly
> and easily
>
> *Customers can buy and sell stock at   the touch of a button.*

Comment: Any reference avaialble?

Comment: @fev Adding now for the related “at the touch of a button” and will hopefully expand later. I’ve come across the phrases I suggested in various writing and in my work in marketing.

Answer (score 0):

***(just) a click away***
phrase

> If something is *(just) a click away*, it is very easy to get on your computer, especially from the Internet:
>
> - All the library's reference materials are now *just a click away*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just-a-click-away))

You can use variants such as

> only a click away, not more than a click away, one click away etc.

Comment: Thank you. is there any expression to not use "click"?

Comment: _[Readily accessible, at your fingertips](https://www.google.com/search?q=at+one%27s+fingertips+meaning&source=hp&ei=Jd94Y7GYKsWqgAb7rYjYCA&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY3jtNZXfO0thcPtHVqOIcFuzFSm8kH_p&oq=at+one%27s+fingertip&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYAjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgARQAFgAYP0MaABwAHgAgAE5iAE5kgEBMZgBAKABAqABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)_...